# Text of first div equals to text of second div equals to html of third div on keyup

Tags: jquery

I am having three div with content editable option and I want that `text` of 1st div = `text` of 2nd div = `html` of 3rd div. I am able to do it in two lines of code but code is not working when I am trying to convert it into single line. Please take a look at my code.

```js
// Working Code
$("#img1").keyup(function() {
  $("#dimg1").html($(this).text());
  $("#oimg1").text($(this).text());
});

// Not Working
$("#img1").keyup(function() {
  $("#dimg1").html($("#oimg1").text($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: `.text()` (without arguments) returns a _String_, while `.text(val)` returns a _jQuery_ object (for chaining). See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/text/) for more info. However, one must ask, what are you gaining by trying to put this all on "one line?" Keeping it as two lines seems perfectly reasonable. One improvement would be to remove the duplicate `$(this).text()` calls, and store that in a variable. `var text = $(this).text(); $(...).html(text); $(...).text(text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, friend. But it's ugly.

```js
$("#img1").keyup(function() {
 $("#dimg1").html($("#oimg1").text($("#img1").text()).text());
});
```

```css
body {display:flex}
div {flex:1 1; height:90vh;border:solid 1px #693}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="img1" contenteditable></div>
<div id="dimg1"></div>
<div id="oimg1"></div>
```